# Get django default model field value to be a parent attribute value

Tags: django, django-models

I want the default modB localField value to be the modA wantedField value corresponding to the foreign key. This would gives :

```
class modA(models.Model):
    wantedField = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    def asDefault():
        return wantedField


class modB(models.Model): 
    moda        = models.ForeignKey(modA)
    localField  = models.CharField(max_length=9,default=moda.asDefault)
```

But moda is a ForeignKey object and as such has no attribute 'asDefault'.
Is what i want to do possible ?

## *update following Kevin Cherepski*

This is where i am now:

```
class modA(models.Model):
    wantedField = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    [ ... other fields ...]
    def asDefault():
        return wantedField

class modB(models.Model): 
    moda        = models.ForeignKey(modA)
    [ ... other fields ...]
    localField  = models.CharField(max_length=9,default=moda.asDefault)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            if self.moda and not self.localField:
                self.localField = self.moda.wantedField
        super(modB, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Also, would the approach be the same with any other field type ?
Anyway, for the moment it returns:

```
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'asDefault'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be done by overriding the save method of modB.

```
class modB(models.Model): 
    moda        = models.ForeignKey(modA)
    localField  = models.CharField(max_length=9,default=moda.asDefault)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.pk is None:
            if self.moda and not self.localField:
                self.localField = self.moda.wantedField
        super(modB, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks. I get : `AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'asDefault'`

Comment: I haven't tested but I believe the error is coming from, 'default=moda.asDefault'

Comment: I have tried a lot of things around `default=moda.asDefault`. But it seems to be a dead end, because it is impossible to deal with effective object at this stage, knowing that models are not fully initiated in models.py

Comment: Could we just remove the default option from localField and rely on overriding save to perform the same functionality?