# Get django ChildInline parent model field values when adding new extra

Tags: python, django, django-admin

As an other way to reach my objective, described there: [Get django default model field value to be a parent attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952047/get-django-default-model-field-value-to-be-a-parent-attribute-value), that is : set a dynamic  default field value to my inline "localwanted" child field, which equals its parent equivalent "remotewanted"

i have the following two models:

```
#models.py
class Parent(models.Model):
    id           = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    remotewanted = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Child(models.Model):
    parent      = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    localwanted = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def parent_remotewanted(self):
        return self.parent.remotewanted
```

If i want localwanted to be "AAA" by default:

```
#admin.py
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Child
        exclude = []
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['localwanted']   = "AAA"        

class ChildInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Child
    extra = 1
    form  = ChildForm

class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = []
    inlines = [ChildInline]
    #list_display, etc
admin.site.register(Parent,ParentAdmin)
```

And it works, with extra fields (only one here) displaying : "AAA"

## BUT

If want this default value to be dynamic (that is to be parent-variable), and replace "AAA" by self.instance.parent_remotewanted, as follows (in the ChildForm class):

```
    ...
    self.initial['localwanted']   = self.instance.parent_remotewanted.__self__
    ...
```

It displays nothing.

## Then

Trying to deal directly with Parent.objects, my second attempt *ceteris paribus*:

```
#models.py
class Child(models.Model):
    parent      = models.ForeignKey(Parent)
    localwanted = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def parent_identity(self): #<----------------
        return self.parent_id  #<----------------

#admin.py
class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Child
        exclude = []
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.initial['localwanted']   = self.instance.parent_identity  #<----------------
```

My inline field displays the Parent id field correctly. Being a newbie, it's magic for me, because "self.instance.parent_identity" is initially not a string object.

```
>>print self.instance.parent_identity
<bound method Child.parent_identity of <Child: >> #<--what print function gives
```

Anyway, i believed that i could play with it, but impossible to reach its string representation so as to do something like:

```
obj = Parent.objects.get(id=self.instance.parent_identity)
# or
obj = Parent.objects.get(id=self.instance.parent_identity.__self__)
```

Both displays "matching query does not exist" with DEBUG = TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True.
I begin to realize what the ChildForm **init** function exactly does. And it seems to deal with structures to fulfil more than with effective objects.

## Questions

Is there something to do from here ?
Is my approach a dead end ?

Answer (score 0):

**instance.parent_identity** is a function, so you have to actually call it.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.initial['localwanted']   = self.instance.parent_identity()  #<----------------
```

oops, it's an old question.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is a function, but dont have to call it now, because the parent class is not instantiated at this point. I changed my perspective and did the trick differently, as explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409900/python-how-to-call-dictionnary-contained-callables-at-a-given-time?noredirect=1#comment43264950_27409900 
To call a callable only when the class object is instantiated, the `@property` decorator was my solution.