# Python : How to call dictionnary-contained callables at a given time?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working with a dictionary object in python which contains numerous keys. Some of their associated value type is of callable type.

Something like :

```
dico = {
    'key1'      : 1,
    'key2'      : 'cars',
    'key3'      : <bound method MyClass.MyMethod_A of <MyClass: MyClass object >>,
    'deeperkeys': {
        'subkey1' : 'space',
        'subkey2' : <bound method MyClass.MyMethod_B of <MyClass: MyClass object >>,
    },
}
```

I know i can do:

```
dico['key3']                  = dico['key3']()
dico['deeperkeys']['subkey2'] = dico['deeperkeys']['subkey2']()
```

Furthermore, notice that i do not work on a unic `dico` as presented above, but on a huge list of `dico`-like dictionaries. Also, i sometimes do not know which keys must be called.
What is the best way to discriminately and transcendentally call all callables ?

## upd

Following Jon Kiparsky, i added a `@property` decorator above each method definition. And it did the trick by taking the problem upside down. No callables but called methods with this decorator to the source definition of `MyClass`. And my lists of dictionaries are generated from it !

Comment: This seems like an "XY" problem: you're asking how to do Y, but it seems like there's an underlying purpose that you should really be asking about. Why do you want to do this? What is your actual goal here?

Comment: whats the type of those values ? `instance` or `class` ?

Comment: The "X" element is that when i define the class, methods definition imply conditional statements on `self.variable`-like variables which are not instantiated at this point. The "Y" element is about calling these callables henceforth instantiated.

Comment: You _could_ obviously just check `if callable(result): result = result()`. (Or maybe even `while` instead of if? Depends what you're doing.) But without knowing why you've stored methods there and what the point is, it's hard to day whether this is a good idea or a very, very bad one.

Comment: What do you mean by "discriminately and transcendentally"?

Comment: But it seems like if you want to delay evaluation of some elements, the simplest thing is usually to delay them all. For values that are constant, you don't need to write a whole method for them, you can just store `lambda: 42` and you get a callable that always returns 42.

Comment: Another option is to use explicit "future" objects of some kind, which avoids confusing yourself by thinking about calling when what you really care about is delayed evaluation. You can write `Future.from_callable(func, *args, **kwargs)` and `Future.from_constant(value)` and get the same kind of object back. (Often you do this so you can later add things like cascaded evaluation, threads or coroutines, or even a whole dataflow variable system, but it's simple enough to do even just to avoid a bit of confusion.)

Comment: @BrenBarn By discriminantly i mean that some of the list-dictionnary-contained values are not callable, thus i do not want to call them. By transcendentally i mean that these callables can be more or less deep in the list of dictionnaries, as suggested by `deeperkeys`.

Comment: @Learner I think I see. I think you might consider looking at the `@property` decorator, which allows you define a function and call it as though it were a field.

Comment: @JonKiparsky: I don't think that's what he wants. That'll still call the method at the time he accesses the property, not later, at the time he accesses the value in the dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't recommend this by any means - see my comment on the original question - nested structures typically call for recursive descent. You'd write a function that examines each of the values in a dict's values() list and does one of three things:

- If the value is callable, call it
- If the value is a dictionary, make a recursive call
- Else, skip it.

Not very different from exploring a file tree, really.

However, and I don't apologize for repeating this, it is important to review your actual problem here and decide if this is really a thing you want to do. I can't see what problem this is a good solution for.

EDIT: based on further information from the OP, it looks like the @property decorator may be what's required. Example of usage:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @property
...     def current_time(self):
...             from datetime import datetime
...             return datetime.now()
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.current_time
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 15, 29, 35, 146096)
>>> f.current_time
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 15, 29, 42, 383874)
```

Note that the syntax evaluates the `current_time` name as if it were a simple value, but the value returned is the result of calling the function, resulting in the value at the time of evaluation, which I think is what you're after.

(but as @abarnert observes, you're putting these into a dictionary, so this isn't going to work for you)

Comment: If you write `dico['key3'] = f.current_time`, it's evaluated immediately; what gets stored in the dictionary is a datetime instance, not a property that will evaluate to a different datetime instance every time you access `dico['key3']`.

Comment: @abarnert You're right - I forgot that these were going into a dict.

Comment: No @JonKiparsky, this is EXACTLY what i was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Why in the world you want to do this is beyond me, but a simple [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) function would work.  Something like:

```
def call_all(dict_or_list):
    if type(dict_or_list) == list:
        for d in dict_or_list:
            call_all(d)
    elif type(dict_or_list) == dict:
        for k, v in dict_or_list.iteritems():
            call_all(v)
    else:
        try:
            dict_or_list()
        except:
            print("Couldn't call:", dict_or_list)
```

That should go through every item of nested dictionaries or lists and try to call them.

Comment: Even if you want type switching, you almost certainly don't want to compare `type(…)` values. Use `isinstance`, and you probably want to use ABCs rather than concrete types. Also, why are you using EAFP to check callability but LBYL to check indexability? Surely if LBYL is needed for lists and dicts it's also needed for callables, and vice-versa?

Comment: You're right, `isinstance` would be better.  I am using EAFP because I honestly have no idea what kind of stuff he has in his dataset that he is wanting to call and I thought it was simpler than coding around the possibilities.  And I type switch just because I iterate through them differently.

Comment: I still don't understand why you think `elif callable(dict_or_list)` or `elif isinstance(dict_or_list, collections.abc.Callable)` wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: I'm certainly not saying or attempting to imply that that wouldn't be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is the `callable` function, which returns true if you pass it something callable and false if you don't.

For example:

```
def undefer(func_or_value):
    if callable(func_or_value):
        return func_or_value()
    else:
        return func_or_value
```

And now you can write:

```
dico['key3'] = undefer(dico['key3'])
```

However, this is probably going to turn out to be a very bad idea. You might not care about the limitations (e.g., now you can't actually store anything callable as a value, and you might want to, say, store a type in there one day), but you obviously care about the confusion engendered by mixing up nullary functions and values as the same kind of thing, because that confusion is what leads to this question in the first place.

What I think you *want* to do is store a dict of nothing but callables, so you always call the value. Some of these callables just return a constant value, but that's fine: just store `lambda: 42` instead of 42.

Or you might want to make things even more explicit. It's not really callability that you care about here; the point of those methods is that they act like deferred values, or futures. You can write a very simple deferred/future class that can be constructed from either a constant or a function call. That also lets you add features like "only call this function the first time, from then on cache the value". But, more importantly, it makes it explicit what you're doing; there's no way to confuse a Future with anything else, error messages from missing a deferral or undeferral will be obvious and trivial to fix, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If it quacks, it is a callable:

```
>>> y=lambda: 'Y'
>>> x='X'
>>> try:
...    z=x()
... except TypeError:
...    z=x
... 
>>> z
'X'
>>> try:
...    z=y()
... except TypeError:
...    z=y
... 
>>> z
'Y'
```

This is a form of [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) by trying to call it and catching the exception if it is not a callable type. In your case, then just assign it.